# Angular directive doesn't read attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple Angular directive that adds a CSS class to an element when being clicked:

```
.directive("addClass", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: "=addClass"
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

            element.on("click", function () {
                element.addClass(scope.name);
                console.log("Element activated");
            });

            element.on("mouseleave", function () {
                element.removeClass(scope.name);
                console.log("Element deactivated");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using it on my links:

```
<a href="" add-class="class-name">...</a>
```

But when I click my link my event handlers execute, although `scope.name` is `undefined`. I could read attribute value using `attributes`, but that beats the purpose of assigning attribute values to scope properties as described in [Angular Directives API](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/guide/directive).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: better to use a template and `ng-click` then handle `click` event directly.  Otherwise, you will need to let Angular know (if you want to manipulate the scope) that you are listening to the DOM by calling `scope.$apply`.

Comment: @DavinTryon I don't think `$apply()` is required here since he's handling the element directly (no digest cycle involved). Besides, his directive seems to be used along with another element, so a custom template couldn't be used.

Comment: @MichaelBenford: Thanks. You're absolutely correct in what you wrote.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Yes, that is why I wrote "if you want to manipulate the scope".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `=addClass` with `@addClass`, or, in case you don't need an isolate scope, just read the class name right out of the `attribute` object:

```
element.on("click", function() {
    element.addClass(attributes.addClass);
    ...
});
```

The reason `=` doesn't work in your case is that it expects a property so a two-way binding can be established and you're providing a static string (I'm assuming you are since `class-name` isn't a valid property name).

Comment: It works, but can you please point me to Angular documentation that talks about these? And when you say: *...it expects a property...* you're referring to which property? `$scope`?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Sure. They have moved some parts of the directive's dev guide into the `$compile` service [page](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.$compile). Look for `isolateScope`.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Yes. If you use `=addClass` then there should be a property named `addClass` in the scope the directive is contained.

Comment: Well from the Documentation it seems that `=addClass` should be the value of the element attribute with the same name. It actually shows how you inject it into isolated scope. I'm not too much of Angular Docs fan. I think they lack much info.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I'm truly sorry. My last comment is totally wrong. `=addClass` means there should be an attribute named `add-class` containing the name of a property in the parent scope so Angular can bind them together. I have no idea why I said it that way. Be angry at me, not at the Angular documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

try `<a href="" add-class="'class-name'">...</a>`, note the single-quoted `'class-name'`